# Imac stuck on loading screen and key combinations are not working

Tags: macos, imac, startup

I would reset my imac but nothing seems to work. I already tried every key combinations but it doesn't work I don't know what to do anymore. I have made a boot usb, but I don't know how to activatie it. The only keys are working is D and C on de by the start. The imac will land on the loading screen and then stuck on 100%.

I have tried to reset the NVRAM/PRAM but i don't see anything. Than i tried to use cmd + r and also nothings. I have tried all of these commands on this link https://support.apple.com/nl-nl/HT201255 but only D and C was working.

with the program Transmac I made a boot usb for mac but I don't see if it does anything.

Comment: First obvious thing - you need to make sure that your keyboard is fine. While keyboard failures are rare, it does happen - my Apple keyboard one day died without any warning. Do you have another keyboard you can use? If keyboard is fine, you need to check connectivity - connect it to a different USB port.

Comment: @sfxedit Yes the keyboard is fine. I am using a windows key board and already tried a different keyboard and same problem happened.

Comment: Ok, please edit your question and add more details - how do you know that the only keys working are D or C? Please describe all the steps you are doing to install macOS using the boot USB?

Comment: Have you tried resetting PRAM/NVRAM, booting into recovery mode, etc? If the Mac is stuck on the boot screen hose do you know only those particular keys work? What model year iMac is this?

Comment: @daneb I tried it but it doesn't work. the model number is MD095 late 2012.

Comment: Did you recently do the Catalina update? There’s a known issue (on the interwebs) where the update causes the Mac to not recognize external hard drives. Can’t remember what I did to get it to work.

Comment: no I did a factory reset. @daneb

Comment: I have/had the same problem on my Late 2013 iMac. In my case, the problem seems to be that I have another external drive (regular HDD) plugged in. If I try to restart or boot up with both external drives attached, I get black screen with an icon showing a folder and a question mark and a URL to support.apple.com/<something>. Similarly, if I try holding down option on startup I just get the internet recovery option. If, instead, I boot up with the HDD unplugged (only the SSD plugged in), everything works as expected. I can then plugin the HDD and things operate normally.

Comment: @yezzy what iMac do you have and what version of macOS are you running?